# Numpy efficient indexing with varied size arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Take a look at this piece of code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random(10)

indicies = [
    np.array([1, 4, 3]),
    np.array([2, 5, 8, 7, 3]),
    np.array([1, 2]),
    np.array([3, 2, 1])
]

result = np.zeros(2)
result[0] = a[indicies[0]].sum()
result[1] = a[indicies[2]].sum()
```

Is there any way to get `result` more efficiently? In my case `a` is a very large array.

In other words I want to select elements from `a` with several varying size index arrays and then sum over them in one operation, resulting in a single array.

Comment: what is the origin of your indices? There are probably some very elegant solutions to your problem a little more upstream

Comment: They are the non-zero elements of a binary Adjacency matrix, (row-wise or column-wise, doesn't matter since the matrix is symmetric). There is another solution, where if the adjacency matrix is `A`, one can write:
`(a[[0,2]][:, None] * A[[0,2], :]).sum(axis=1)` but I am not sure if this is more efficient. And if you replace `A` with sparse matrix then it doesn't even work. In other words, for a subset of nodes (in the example [0, 2]), sum the value in the array `a` for all of their neighbor nodes)

Comment: Scipy sparse performs things like row summation with matrix multiplication.  So `A.dot(a)` might work

Comment: Results[1] and indices[2] - is the 1 and 2 mix right?

Comment: For clarity, that meant I want result for 2 index arrays, which happen to be the 0th and 2nd, so put them in the resulting array at position 0 and 1. Could have been any. it was just a random example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your `a` and `indicies` list:

```
In [280]: [a[i].sum() for i in indicies]
Out[280]: 
[1.3986792680307709,
 2.6354365193743732,
 0.83324677494990895,
 1.8195179021311731]
```

Which of course could wrapped in `np.array()`.

For a subset of the `indicies` items use:

```
In [281]: [a[indicies[i]].sum() for i in [0,2]]
Out[281]: [1.3986792680307709, 0.83324677494990895]
```

A comment suggests `indicies` comes from an Adjacency matrix, possibly sparse.

I could recreate such an array with:

```
In [289]: A=np.zeros((4,10),int)
In [290]: for i in range(4): A[i,indicies[i]]=1
In [291]: A
Out[291]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

and use a matrix product (`np.dot`) to do the selection and sum:

```
In [292]: A.dot(a)
Out[292]: array([ 1.39867927,  2.63543652,  0.83324677,  1.8195179 ])
```

`A[[0,2],:].dot(a)` would use a subset of rows.

A sparse matrix version has that list of row indices:

```
In [294]: Al=sparse.lil_matrix(A)
In [295]: Al.rows
Out[295]: array([[1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5, 7, 8], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]], dtype=object)
```

And a matrix product with that gives the same numbers:

```
In [296]: Al*a
Out[296]: array([ 1.39867927,  2.63543652,  0.83324677,  1.8195179 ])
```

Comment: I did think of `A[[0,2],:].dot(a)` as well but I thought that is not quite as nice since the `A` matrix is `NxN` and `N` is large. Then I tried to do it with sparse matrix but could not get it working. Now I realise that `*` is actually a dot product for sparse matrix which is diffrent then 2D dense arrays where it's actually a normal multiplication. Weird. So, doing `A1[[0,2], :] * a` works.

Comment: In MATLAB `*` is matrix multiplication, and `.*` elemental.  Sparse matrices are modeled on `np.matrix` which copies MATLAB.  Newer python added `@` for matrix mult use.

Comment: Yeah apparently `*`, is overloaded to be matrix multiplication for type `np.matrix` and `*` elementwise multiplication for type `np.array`. Should have known :)

Answer (score -1):

If your array **a** is very large you might have **memory issues** if your array of indices contains many arrays of many indices when looping through it.

To avoid this issue use an iterator instead of a list :

```
indices = iter(indices)
```

and then loop through your iterator.

Comment: Well, how calling `iter` on an object that is already loaded in RAM would help reduce memory consumption? Moreover, if you simply do `for something in indices: ... `, Python will do `iter(indices)` implicitly for you.